# numero pares,impares,zero e maior que 10 como achar?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

```
For g = 1 To 10
For f = 1 To 10

  Cells(f, g) = Int(100 * Rnd())
  k = Cells(f, g)

 If Int(k / 2) - k / 2 = 0 Then

        pares = pares + 1

    Else

        Impares = Impares + 1

    End If

    If k = 0 Then Zeros = Zeros + 1

    If k > 10 Then MaioresQuedez = MaioresQuedez + 1


Cells(12, 2) = pares & " números Pares"

Cells(14, 2) = Impares & " números Ímpares"

Cells(16, 2) = Zeros & " números Zero"

Cells(18, 2) = MaioresQuedez & " números maiores do que 10"


Next f
Next g
```

Comment: Será que não é melhor ir lendo cada célula, ver se tem valor, e comparar o valor com o que você precisa? Para números ímpares, basta ver se o resto da divisão por 2 é 1. Estou colocando a lógica pra ver se te ajuda, já que não domino vb.

Comment: já tentei mas não conseguir.

Comment: Não ficou claro para mim o uso da variável W. Por isso fiz o exemplo somente para a variável K. Se for a W ou ambas, basta adaptar o código. Luana, edite sua pergunta para não usar fotos ou "PrintScreen" no caso de códigos, dá para fazer o mesmo para resultados. Assim: no cabeçalho do texto da pergunta, há os colchetes "{ }", use para "colar" ou digitar o código que fez. Há o ícone para inserir "imagens". Você pode "copiar" a área da planilha que quer mostrar e"colar" nesta área. Também pode editar a tela do "PrintScreen", no Word com a opção "Formatar" e "Cortar" e colar nesta área.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como exemplo, usei somente a variável K, pode fazer o mesmo para outras variráveis se for o caso.

Antes do "loop" zere as variáveis"

```
Pares = 0

Impares = 0

Zeros = 0

MaioresQueDez = 0
```

Coloque isto dentro do "loop" e/ou adapte para outras variáveis:

```
    If Int(K/2) - K/2 = 0 then 

        Pares = Pares + 1 

    Else 

        Impares = Impares + 1 

    End If

    If K = 0 Then Zeros = Zeros + 1

    If K > 10 Then MaioresQueDez = MaioresQueDez + 1
```

Como houve modificações na pergunta exposta, eu testei seu código e ele está correto, porém altere as saídas como mostro abaixo, pois da forma que fez, está sobrepondo valores na matriz.

Coloque isso após o "loop":

```
    Cells(12, 2) = Pares & " números Pares"

    Cells(14, 2) = Impares & "números Ímpares"

    Cells(16, 2) = Zeros & " números Zero"

    Cells(18, 2) = MaioresQueDez & " números maiores do que 10"
```

Comment: Oi Luana, resolveu com a explicação acima? Seria legal você editar sua pergunta fazendo o que sugeri no outro comentário, assim você vai pegando o jeito de lidar com as questões aqui no Soft.

Comment: oi leo, fiz aqui mas não deu certo apareceu alguns números outros não!

Comment: Mas o que deu errado? Não há falha no código. Você colocou nas posições indicadas? São três partes: antes do loop (for next), no meio e depois do loop. Dê mais informações se tiver dificuldade, e avise se der certo. Pode ser por causa das células que usei iguais as suas, vou editar a terceira parte (a saída dos valores), acho que sobrepôs e você não está vendo completo. Veja se apareceram as respostas completamente.

Comment: Como assim ( for next ) não estou entendo ?

Comment: Você tem dois, For F = ... For G = ...   ... Next G ... Next F. Estes sao os loops.

Comment: Luana, copie seu código para a pergunta (edite ela), apague a foto e dê 4 espaços pelo menos em cada linha do seu código no texto, assim ele entenderá e mostrará como "código na tela". Dai eu pego seu código e complemento com o meu, mas precisa estar em formato texto como indiquei para eu poder adaptá-lo.

Comment: já editei como fiz.

Comment: Luana, veja minha resposta, lá eu explico, funcionou o que você fez, mas precisa mudar a parte final como eu mostro para entender a sobreposição e depois adaptar como quiser. Não deixe de marcar a resposta, e vamos para a próxima...

Comment: leo, agora sim deu certo muito obrigada por está me ajudando!!